# Spring boot : Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, intellij-idea

I obtain this error when try to start multi module maven spring-boot project on IntelliJ:

#### Unable to start embedded Tomcat

The same project on Eclipse STS run correctly without error.

This is a log:

`2019-04-14 12:19:29.058 ERROR [tracking,,,] 1877 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'traceWebFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'traceWebFilter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tracingFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tracingFilter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceHttpAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientParser'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'httpClientParser' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/TraceHttpAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'httpClientParser' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.TraceAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'spanReporters'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'zipkinReporter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/zipkin2/ZipkinAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'reporter' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'zipkinSender' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/zipkin2/sender/ZipkinRestTemplateSenderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [zipkin2.reporter.Sender]: Factory method 'restTemplateSender' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException`

do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have "jackson-databind" dependency in your pom.xml? What version is used?

Comment: jackson-databind version 2.7.4 in my pom. I have a IntelliJ CE, which officially does not support SpringBoot and not support Application server. But if I unload a project from Spring Initializr it works correctly